# Creating ordered list of next 15 events

Tags: fullcalendar

We have FullCalendar in use on a community website. There are a large number of events and we would like to add a summary list of the next 15 events (by date).  I visualise it being an ordered list with links to the details of the events - so basically the same information / functionality that appears for an event on the calendar but presented as a separate list.  Is this possible? Any ideas on how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

[Yes, use an AJAX function to fetch events](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_function/) that way you can do two things:
populate your calendar and use the same events data to populate some other DOM element.